# How to check if contours are the same?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I've got two images, the second one is the first one after modification. I find contours of two images and then check if there any same contours. The problem is, that despite contours being the same (drawing contours of one image and another one gives totally same results) after checking that it never becomes true that one contour is equal to any another.

**The code:**
Finding the contours:

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<MatOfPoint> contours2 = new ArrayList<>();
Imgproc.findContours(contours1mat, contours1, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
Imgproc.findContours(contours2mat, contours2, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Checking the contours (it never makes match variable true):

```
for(int i = 0; i < contours1.size(); i++)
{
    boolean match = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < contours2.size(); j++)
    {
        if (contours1.get(i) == contours2.get(j))
        {
            //never hits that place, despite passing through all contours
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!match)
    {
        contours1.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?** Is this way of checking the similarity of the contours is incorrect? If so, how can I check if two contours are the same? How would You check the contour match if you would need to?

**First image:**

[image]

**Second image:**

[image]

The logic behind the second image is that it is the first image but with holes punched in it. I am checking if those holes cross the side of the white zone, if it does not, there should be two same contours in first and second image. **I am only finding the outer contours**, so the contour size is the same in both images.

**...**

**UPDATE!!!**
This code gives me the desired result, but the problem is that it is really **time consuming**, and, obviously, there is a huge room for improvement in the algorythm itself (probably some approximation of contours could be done before the check) or the method I use. I really hope that there is an easy direct result to solve my issue. Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < contours1.size(); i++)
{
    boolean match = true;

    for (int j = 0; j < contours2.size(); j++)
    {
        if (contours1.get(i).toArray().length == contours2.get(j).toArray().length)
        {
            boolean match2 = true;
            for (int k = 0; k < contours1.get(i).toArray().length; k++)
            {
                if ((contours1.get(i).toArray()[k].x != contours2.get(j).toArray()[k].x) ||
                    (contours1.get(i).toArray()[k].y != contours2.get(j).toArray()[k].y))
                {
                    match2 = false;
                }
            }
            if (match2)
            {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            match = false;
    }

    if (!match)
    {
        contours1.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality operator `==` doesn't work for objects the way it works for primitives.

For `int`s, `char`s, `boolean`s, etc. comparing with `==` checks if their values are equal. For objects, it checks if the two variables refer to the same object, not if the fields within the objects are the same. In order to check for objects being equivalent, there is the method `.equals()`, which would be used like this:

```
if (contours1.get(i).equals(contours2.get(i)))
```

However, this will default to the same behavior as `==`, checking if the two variables refer to the same object. In your `MatOfPoint` class, you will need to override the `.equals()` method to define how it should check for two objects being "equal".

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I had a similar problem and I used this algorithm: A multi-scale curve smoothing for generalised pattern recognition (MSGPR). See [link1](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00132897/document) and [link2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1224905).

This works really for close patterns, but in your case you could first fill the patterns, and then extract the contour.

Comment: The article you gave me is super interesting and useful, but it is for checking between two similar, not same contours. In my situation I have completely similar contours to find. Despite that, again, thanks for that article, really fascinating.

Comment: From experience, contours are never exact because of the discretization process. So there will always be some pixels that may be different or not is the exact same order. In that case, this paper makes sense.

Comment: I understand your point, but in my situation they are completely the same, because the second image is just the modified first one, it has holes in its white zones. My task is to find wether those holes crosses the borders of the white zones and changes the outer contours and I solved this problem (I edited the question), but my method is quite time consuming (though abolishing any error ability), so I am thinking of more direct and faster way to check this contour matching, or only optimise the code I've given. If my contours would not be 100% the same, your given article would be an answer.

Comment: Ok, in this specific case, you don't need the algorithm I pointed. Good luck with your project.